# Generic class - getClass().getName()

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic base class:

```
public class BaseLabel<T> extends JXLabel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BaseLabel() {
        System.out.println(T.class.getClass().getName()); //error
    }       
}
```

and Child class:

```
public class ChildLabel extends BaseLabel<ChildLabel> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    public ChildLabel() {

    }       
}
```

I am getting compilation error.

Is there any way to get the actual class name from the constructor of BaseClass. Here, by actual class I am referring to that class, which I am going to instantiate.

For example I am instantiating ChildClass, `ChildClass clz = new ChildClass()`;

then that `println()` will print `package.ChildClass`.

Thanks in advance.

---

The compilation error is:

```
cannot select from a type variable System.out.println(T.class.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

---

If I call `this.getClass.getSimpleName()` from the `abstract BaseClass`'s constructor. It is printing the `ChildClass`.

Why?

Is it due to, as I am instantiating `ChildClass` so this is pointing to the `ChildClass`'s object.

Comment: You're asking for information that is not available at compile time, so as far as I know, what you're trying to do is impossible. Even at run time however you'll run into Java generic limitations on getting this information. Please read this article, especially the part about generics and type erasure: [Java theory and practice: Generics gotchas](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html)

Comment: What does the compilation error say?

Comment: @ewok, yes I am importing JXLabel.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels thanks for your explanation. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ugly? yes

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;


public class GenericClass<T> {

    public GenericClass() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getGenericSuperclass()); //output: GenericClass<Foo>
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]); //output: class Foo
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChildClass();
    }

}
```

child class

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;


public class ChildClass extends GenericClass<Foo> {

    public ChildClass() {
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]); //output: class Foo
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to find this information from your class `BaseLabel` at run time as it doesn't 'know' what type it's generic has been instantiated with. This is because Java uses type erasure for generics - generic parameters aren't runtime artefacts.

Comment: @matthewSpleep Thank you very much for explanation. If I call this.getClass.getSimpleName() from the abstract BaseClass's constructor. It is printing the ChildClass. Can you tell me why it is behaving like this? Is it due to as I am instantiating ChildClass so this is pointing to the ChildClass's object.

Comment: Java methods are resolved dynamically (using the runtime class of the object) the getClass() call still knows that the object is ultimately a `ChildLabel` even though the code is invoked in `BaseLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

```
((Class<?>)((ParameterizedType) clazz.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).getName();
```

Did the job.